# How to temporary pause window restarts for updates from a python script?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I have built an application that often runs overnight but sometimes windows decide to restart even though the program is still running. This is problematic for both me and some users for obvious reasons.

I cannot expect the users to manually select the update pause bottom, hence, I want the automatic restart to be disabled by the program while it is running. Is there a way to automate this?

To note; I'm running my application from a jupyter notebook which might be important.

Thanks for any ideas.